# Is JWT authentication needed for login/logout

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, jwt

I have recently started working on securing my web applications.I'm using Spring Framework.So I've already applied JWT authentication for securing my REST API endpoints.And I have also created a different sample demo wherein I provide simple login and logout functionality using Spring Security.

Now I'm trying to use JWT authentication for the login/logout functionality.But I feel its somehow wrong.I'm in the opinion that JWT should be used only for securing endpoints of REST services and not login/logout functionality which is a stateful activity and JWT  authentication is not the best method for that.

Is this a misconception I'm having?Can JWT also be used for login/logout?Any input to it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT (JSON Web Token) is a self-contained access token format. In the OAuth 2.0 world, an access token (eg. JWT) is sent in the request to a protected resource and the OAuth 2.0 Resource Server enforces authorization by validating the access token and introspecting it for authorities that it would use for authorization decisioning. The key point here is that a JWT is used for authorization NOT authentication. [OpenID Connect 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) is used for authenticating users.

Spring Security 5.1 supports both OpenID Connect 1.0 via the [`oauth2Login()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login) feature as well as JWT on the [`oauth2ResourceServer()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver) feature.

For a complete sample see [OAuth 2.0 Protocols and Patterns](https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2-protocol-patterns) along with the [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrmQH5SqraA).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have already answered most part of your Question.
You can have `stateful/stateless` authentication.
Now which one to use depends on Usecases of Application.

**Usecase 1:**

If your application is deployed as a service which require all execution to be done from UI, stateful authentication i.e Form based Authentication can be considered.

**Usecase 2:**

Lets say you are creating APIs for 3rd party and want to secure them, go for stateless authentication i.e JWT

**Usecase 3:**

Now if your usecase is both Usecase 1,2, you can also implement Form based/JWT authentication in one application.

**Note:**

Having said that you can use Token authentication for Login as well.
Only catch is you have to write a few scenarios on your own.

Eg:

1. When Login is successful add Token in `localStorage` and use if for further requests.
2. On Logout delete the token from `localStorage`.
3. For any access without token Redirect to Login screen with Error msg.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But looking at alternative solution for authentication other than jwt.